# Programmatic file upload with chunking: Only the first file is sent

Tags: jquery, file-upload, blueimp

When doing a [programmatic file upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/API#programmatic-file-upload) using the [jQuery-File-Upload plugin](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) with chunking enabled I can not get more than one file to be sent.

I am making the call as follows:

```
fileUploadWidget.fileupload('send',
{
    files: filesList
})
```

`filesList` is a list of File objects.

Also I have set maxChunkSize and set singleFileUploads to true (I also tried false) as indicated on the [Options wiki page](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options#maxchunksize).

Has anyone had any success getting this to work?

**Update:**

I'd made an [issue](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/issues/2525) on GitHub for this problem and here's the response from the author:

> [...] Chunked uploads only support one file per request.
>   That is, you can still simultaneously upload multiple files in chunks, but you'll have to send mutliple requests for that.

---

**Our Solution:**

As has been already commented, and what we ended up doing, was to send the files in a loop where `widget` was initialized with [sequentialUploads](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options#sequentialuploads) set to `true` (you'll want this depending on how your backend is configured):

```js
// for illustration only
// does not do anything with the returned jqXHR objects
for (i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    widget.fileupload('send', { files: files[i] });
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using [Plupload](http://www.plupload.com/) instead?  I've recently done a lot of work with multiple file uploads and found the plugin was exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

If you use C# as back-end, you can try this (Client-Side, JQuery):

```
 $("#btnUpload").click(function () { // btnUpload is the ID of any button for upload
            var formdata = new FormData(); //FormData object
            var fileInput = document.getElementById('fileInput');
            //Iterating through each files selected in fileInput
            for (i = 0; i < fileInput.files.length; i++) {
                //Appending each file to FormData object
                formdata.append(fileInput.files[i].name, fileInput.files[i]);
            }
            //Creating an XMLHttpRequest and sending
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open('POST', '/UploadMethod'); // UploadMethod is your back-end code
            xhr.send(formdata);
            xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
                    // alert("uploaded");
                    }
            }

        });
```

and then in you UploadMethod do something like this: (ServerSide , C#)

```
public void Upload()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < Request.Files.Count; i++)
            {
                HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files[i]; //Uploaded file
                //Use the following properties to get file's name, size and MIMEType
                int fileSize = file.ContentLength;
                string fileName = file.FileName;
                string mimeType = file.ContentType;
                System.IO.Stream fileContent = file.InputStream;
                //To save file, use SaveAs method
                var appPath = HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath + "Documents/" + "_" +  DateTime.Now+ fileName;

                file.SaveAs(appPath); //File will be saved in Documents folder
              }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach(files in filesList.length)
{
    fileUploadWidget.fileupload('send',
    {
        files:filesList
    }
}
```

Maybe not precisely the correct formatting but you get the idea :)

Answer (score 0):

You should do like this:

```
$('collection object').each(function () {
$(this).fileupload({'send',
    files: $(this)
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You basically send them in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is from your html. use something like this for the file field

```
<input type='file' name="pics[]" />
```

The name attribute should array then you can get with loop from backend